# Scala equivalent to Haskell pattern Matching on constructors

Tags: scala, haskell

In Haskell I have got constructors defined like this :

```
data Fonction =
Const Float
    | Param String
    | Var String
    | Add Fonction Fonction

infix 3 @+

(@+) :: Fonction -> Fonction -> Fonction
(@+) (Const k) (Const k') = Const (k + k')
```

In Scala, quite new for me,  I tried :

```
trait Function {
  case class Const(value: Double) extends Function
  case class Param(value: String) extends Function
  case class Var(value: String) extends Function
  case class Add(f1: Function, f2: Function) extends Function
}

object Op extends Function {
   def som(f1:Function, f2: Function): Function  = 
    (f1, f2) match {
       case (Const(a),Const(b)) => Const(a + b)
       case _  => Add(f1,f2)
   }  
}

object HelloWorld extends Function {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s =  Op.som(Const(3),Const(5))
    println(s)
   }
}
```

but the pattern (Const(3), Const(5)) isn't matched since I get `Add(Const(3.0),Const(5.0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although @nicodp code is technically correct (but IMHO not quite), it provides no explanation. The reason why your code doesn't work as expect is because you define your cases inside `trait Function`. The thing is that in the Java world [inner classes can be static and non-static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) and Scala copies this part of the behavior. And classes defined inside a `trait` are non-static. Particularly it means that an instance of `HelloWorld.Const(42)` is not equal to an instance of `Op.Const(42)` because they capture different "outer" values of different types (the `Op` object and the `HelloWorld` object). And this is also why your pattern matching doesn't work as you might expect. If you make you write your pattern matching as:

```
object Op extends Function {
  def som(f1: Function, f2: Function): Function =
    (f1, f2) match {
      // this doesn't work
      //case (Const(a), Const(b)) => Const(a + b) 
      // this works
      case (HelloWorld.Const(a), HelloWorld.Const(b)) => Const(a + b)
      case _ => Add(f1, f2)
    }
}
```

it will work but this is probably not what you want. The way to work this around is to define your `case class`es in a static context. You may do it in just top level as in @nicodp suggested. Another choice is to put them into a `Function` a [companion object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html) like this:

```
sealed trait Function 

object Function {
  case class Const(value: Double) extends Function
  case class Param(value: String) extends Function
  case class Var(value: String) extends Function
  case class Add(f1: Function, f2: Function) extends Function
}

object Op {

  import Function._

  def som(f1: Function, f2: Function): Function =
    (f1, f2) match {
      //          case (HelloWorld.Const(a), HelloWorld.Const(b)) => Const(a + b)
      case (Const(a), Const(b)) => Const(a + b)
      case _ => Add(f1, f2)
    }
}

object HelloWorld {
  import Function._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s = Op.som(Const(3), Const(5))
    println(s)
  }
}
```

Note that you replace `extends Function` with `import Function._`

Also note that it is suggested to use `sealed` on such traits so you (compiler) know your pattern-matching is exhaustive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Interesting.
I got a strange warning though :

    `defined object Function
    warning: previously defined trait Function is not a companion to object Function.
    Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.`

Comment: @user9258411, You should put `object Function` and `sealed trait Function` in the same file and in the same package. In other words they should be a part of the same "compilation unit". I'm not sure what happens in REPL. Probably you should define both in a single input action and that's probably yhy `:paste` is suggested to you.

Comment: Yes I got this only in the REPL. Thanks

Comment: @user9258411, if some answer helped you (and this doesn't have to be the most upvoted one i.e. not necessary mine in this question), you should mark that answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The types you have created are [path dependent](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/13/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-13-path-dependent-types.html). Change the type declaration to this:

```
trait Function

object Function {
  case class Const(value: Double) extends Function
  case class Param(value: String) extends Function
  case class Var(value: String) extends Function
  case class Add(f1: Function, f2: Function) extends Function
}

import Function._
```

With your original defintion the `Const` need to be created inside of the same `Function` object to match. You are matching inside of `Op`, but the `Const` you are matching are created inside of `HelloWorld`, therefore you are matching `HelloWorld.Const` againt `Op.Const`.

Is there any reason why `Op` and `HelloWorld` are derived from the `Function` trait? (You do not use this in your example, but perhaps you have some reason out of that). Following would look more natural to me:

```
object HelloWorld {
  def som(f1:Function, f2: Function): Function  = {
    (f1, f2) match {
      case (Const(a), Const(b)) => Const(a + b)
      case _ => Add(f1, f2)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s =  som(Const(3),Const(5))
    println(s)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To define this piece of `Haskell` in `Scala`:

```
data Fonction =
Const Float
    | Param String
    | Var String
    | Add Fonction Fonction
```

I'd proceed as follows:

```
trait Function

case class Const(v: Float) extends Function
case class Param(v: String) extends Function
case class Var(v: String) extends Function
case class Add(f1: Function, f2: Function) extends Function
```

And now your code will work as expected:

```
scala> HelloWorld.main(Array())
Const(8.0)
```